# Create list view powershell and create filter

Tags: list, powershell

I have the below script to create a list view in a specific library.  I have a metadata field 'Country' that I wish to filter on.  I have looked at the query needed and pasted it into my code and it fails.

```
#DefaultView property$viewDefaultView = $false

#Get destination site and list
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://site"
$list = $web.GetList(($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd("/") + "/General"))

$viewTitle = "BE" #Title property
#Add the column names from the ViewField property to a string collection
$viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$viewFields.Add("DocIcon") > $null
$viewFields.Add("LinkFilename") > $null
$viewFields.Add("Modified") > $null
$viewFields.Add("Editor") > $null
$viewFields.Add("FileSizeDisplay") > $null
#Query property
$viewQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>"
#RowLimit property
$viewRowLimit = 50
#Paged property
$viewPaged = $true
#DefaultView property
$viewDefaultView = $true

#Create the view in the destination list
$newview = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView)
Write-Host ("View '" + $newview.Title + "' created in list '" + $list.Title + "' on site " + $web.Url)
$web.Dispose()
```

Here is my query

```
$viewQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" /></OrderBy>
                            <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Country" /><Value Type="
                            Text">BE</Value></Eq></Where>"
```

So as you can see I want to filter on BE as the country but I get this error

```
At C:\CreateListViewCty.ps1:9 char:32
+ $viewFields = {_UIVersionString, DocIcon, LinkFilename, Modified.
+                                ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At C:\CreateListViewCty.ps1:18 char:40
+ $viewQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><
Fie ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
Unexpected token 'LinkFilename" /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Country"
 /><Value Type="Text">BE</Value></Eq></Where>"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

Comment: Your working query has single quotes and your broken query has double quotes. There's your problem.

Comment: Greats thanks, still learning PS.  One more question.  I can now create the view but value BE isn't be put in.  So I have the Country selected and is equals to but BE isn't there.  Is it because it is a term from MMS?

Comment: Sounds like your query is wrong. Use something like CamlDesigner to help build it. http://www.camldesigner.com/

Comment: Perfect, that has solved it.  CamlDesigner is now my best friend!